# Java Reflection : Accessing getter method

Tags: java, reflection

The code

```
import java.beans.*
for (PropertyDescriptor pd : Introspector.getBeanInfo(Foo.class).getPropertyDescriptors()) {
    if (pd.getReadMethod() != null && !"class".equals(pd.getName()))
        System.out.println(pd.getReadMethod().invoke(foo));
}
```

This code returns the getters of the class but I am trying to access the getters in the order of attributes where I can set their values to.

How can I access the getters in particualr order?

Comment: What order are you expecting?  The JVM does not guarantee any specific ordering.

Comment: @ChrisK In case if I have id , name , I would like to getid() and then getName(). but the code above doesn't provide any specific order

Comment: Have you considered sorting, using a custom comparator?  eg https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DEfine the class, then in the instance get all the methods then use a stream to filter the getters only

```
public class Pint {

    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int z;

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public int getZ() {
        return z;
    }
```

and then

```
 Arrays.stream(p.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()).filter(x -> x.getName().contains("get")).forEach(System.out::println);
```